# List to Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Basically I have a list like this:

```
['  ROOT S . ', '  ROOT S ! ', '  ROOT is it true that S ? ', ' ', '  S   NP VP ', '  VP  Verb NP ', '  NP DT Noun ', '  NP NP PP ', '  PP Prep NP ', '  Noun Adj Noun ', ' ', '  Verb ate ', '  Verb wanted ', '  Verb kissed ', '  Verb understood ', '  Verb pickled ', ' ', '  DT the ', '  DT a ', '  DT  every ', ' ', '  Noun president ', '  Noun sandwich ', '  Noun pickle ', '  Noun chief of staff ', '  Noun floor ', ' ', '  Adj fine ', '  Adj delicious ', '  Adj perplexed ', '  Adj pickled ', ' ', '  Prep    with ', '  Prep on ', '  Prep under ', '  Prep    in ']
```

I would like to separate the first value from the rest of each entry and put it into a dictionary so for example for the first value in the list would be input into the dictionary line this:

```
Key=ROOT
Value=S .
```

and if there is multiple of the same kind id like to separate them by |.
Heres what id like to dictionary to look like sort of

```
ROOT = 'S . | S ! | is it true that S ?',
S  = 'NP VP',
VP = 'Verb NP',
NP = 'DT Noun | NP PP',
PP = 'Prep NP',
Noun = 'Adj Noun | president | sandwich | pickle | chief of staff | floor',
DT = 'the | a | every',
Verb  = 'ate | wanted | kissed | understood | pickled',
Adj = 'fine | delicious | perplexed | pickled',
Prep = 'with | on | under | in'
```

Is there any way to do this without using external libraries?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, try `strip` and `split` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using any libraries or modules:

```
x = ['  ROOT S . ', '  ROOT S ! ', '  ROOT is it true that S ? ', ' ', '  S   NP VP ', '  VP  Verb NP ', '  NP DT Noun ', '  NP NP PP ', '  PP Prep NP ', '  Noun Adj Noun ', ' ', '  Verb ate ', '  Verb wanted ', '  Verb kissed ', '  Verb understood ', '  Verb pickled ', ' ', '  DT the ', '  DT a ', '  DT  every ', ' ', '  Noun president ', '  Noun sandwich ', '  Noun pickle ', '  Noun chief of staff ', '  Noun floor ', ' ', '  Adj fine ', '  Adj delicious ', '  Adj perplexed ', '  Adj pickled ', ' ', '  Prep    with ', '  Prep on ', '  Prep under ', '  Prep    in ']

d = {}
for k, v in (s.lstrip().split(' ',1) for s in x if ' ' in s.lstrip()):
    if k in d:
        d[k]+='|' + v
    else:
        d[k]=v
```

This produces the dictionary:

```
{'Adj': 'fine |delicious |perplexed |pickled ',
 'DT': 'the |a | every ',
 'NP': 'DT Noun |NP PP ',
 'Noun': 'Adj Noun |president |sandwich |pickle |chief of staff |floor ',
 'PP': 'Prep NP ',
 'Prep': '   with |on |under |   in ',
 'ROOT': 'S . |S ! |is it true that S ? ',
 'S': '  NP VP ',
 'VP': ' Verb NP ',
 'Verb': 'ate |wanted |kissed |understood |pickled '}
```

#### How it works

This initializes an empty dictionary:

```
d = {}
```

This starts a loop over all the items in list `x`:

```
for k, v in (s.lstrip().split(' ',1) for s in x if ' ' in s.lstrip()):
```

This list generator has the form

```
(function(s) for s in x if condition(s))
```

So, it extracts, in turn, each string `s` from list `x`.  Strings `s` are ignored unless they pass the condition which in our case is: `' ' in s.lstrip()`.  This condition simply assures that there is at least one space after the first word in `s`.  In other words, this removes malformed or empty entries.

The generator returns the key and value using: `s.lstrip().split(' ',1)`.  This extracts the first word from `s` to use as the key and all that remains after that word is the value.

The following adds the items found to the dictionary:

```
    if k in d:
        d[k]+='|' + v
    else:
        d[k]=v
```

Answer (score 1):

One useful approach might be:

```
   import collections
   dl = collections.defaultdict(list)
   for s in thelist:
       k, _, v = s.strip().partition(' ')
       dl[k].append(v)
   d = dict((k, ' | '.join(dl[k])) for k in dl)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {}

for item in list:
   _item = item.strip()
   split_item  = _item.split(" ",1)
   key = split_item[0]
   if key in dict:
       dict[key] = dict[key] + "|" + split_item[1] 
   else:
       dict[key] = split_item[1]
```